# Does not have or hasn't

Tags: comprehension

1.He hasn't enough money to attend the concert.

2.He does not have enough money to attend the concert.

I've found the second one in my text book. And  I am confuse that does the first one is correct with the same meaning?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is technically grammatical, but it is archaic and not very idiomatic in Present-Day English, at least in the US. The second sentence is more common and natural. Both sentences have the same meaning.

Comment: The first is somewhat more common in British dialects, but the "doesn't have" is still more common and natural.